# if statement with OR operator

Tags: c++, if-statement, operators

I am writing this code on Visual Studio 2013.

When I execute the code by answering (1) for the first question, the program still asks me the second question.

Shouldn't the program skip the second question if I answered (1) to the first question?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Answer questions with 0 or 1" << endl;
    cout << "Is there a deep discount on your favorite car? ";
    bool Discount = false;
    cin >> Discount;

    cout << "Did you get a fantastic bonus? ";
    bool FantasticBonus = false;
    cin >> FantasticBonus;

    if (Discount || FantasticBonus)
        cout << "Congratulations, you can buy that car!" << endl;
    else
    cout << "Sorry, waiting a while is a good idea" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should it? Your program will ask one question, then the other then output one message or the other. If you want to do something, then you must code it.

Answer (score 2):

It will not skip the second question since there is no condition before the second question after the first answer. If you want to skip the second question when you enter 1 for the first answer:

```
bool FantasticBonus = false;
if(!Discount) {
    cout << "Did you get a fantastic bonus? ";
    cin >> FantasticBonus;
}
```